# Adding CSV layer in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv, import, point-creation

I am trying to load a series of CSV files as vectors in PyQGIS. I run this code to try to get the first one:

```py
uri = 'file://D:/Saved Stuff/gulags/1.40.csv?delimiter=;&yField=y&xField=x'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, '1.40', 'delimitedtext')
layer.isValid()
False
```

Obviously it won't load when I run `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)`. When I add the CSV manually to a map it loads fine. Here is what that looks like

> name;y;x;total
>
> AMURSKII ZhELEZNODOROZhNYI ITL;51.375889;128.134147;84053
>
> BELOMORO-BALTIISKII ITL;62.912774;34.456850;78918
>
> BIRSKII ITL;48.999752;132.461997;11634

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What happens when you do this? uri='file://D:/Saved Stuff/gulags/1.40.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s' % (";","x","y");

Comment: Still gives me false. The modulo is just a standin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was with your URI. (note the third slash)

Use the following as a working example:

```
uri = 'file:///D:/Saved Stuff/gulags/1.40.csv?delimiter=;&yField=y&xField=x'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, '1.40', 'delimitedtext')
```