# Batch converting ASCII text-files to shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, batch, ascii

Here is a sample of my source data.

```
682575.040,5769613.850,153.410,87
682575.990,5769611.700,153.470,91
682575.850,5769613.340,153.530,95
682580.120,5769612.860,153.480,88
682580.270,5769613.760,153.470,83
682579.430,5769615.690,153.400,90
682577.800,5769628.040,153.450,94
682580.510,5769622.020,153.440,93
682581.370,5769620.100,153.480,86
682582.430,5769617.740,153.530,95
```

And this is the script I am trying to use:

```py
import os.path, glob
layers=[]
for file in glob.glob('D:/Projects/RPope/LLPG/Lidar/2007/ascii/test/*.txt'): # Change this base path
  uri = "file:///" + file + "?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&useHeader=no&crs=epsg:28354" % (",", "xField","yField")
  vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, os.path.basename(file), "delimitedtext")
  vlayer.addAttributeAlias(0,'X')
  vlayer.addAttributeAlias(1,'Y')
  vlayer.addAttributeAlias(2,'Z')
  vlayer.addAttributeAlias(3,'code')
  layers.append(vlayer)
```

Here is the Error message.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in run-code
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'addAttributeAlias'
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166517/adding-a-csv-layer-in-pyqgis it looks like the attributes are specified in the constructor rather than added later, give that a try and see if it works for you. The example though has a header row so I'm not exactly certain how to modify the layer to use enumerated columns rather than header specified field columns.

Comment: AddAttributeAlias has been renamed. Extract from  the QGIS API documentation: "Renamed addAttributeAlias() to setFieldAlias()" (see: https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html).